# PHP & Symfony: Passenger error #2

Tags: php

Two years ago I'm helping friend to recover http://cipg.or.id/ because the original developer has passed away. And succeeded.
Recently the hosting account has been suspended and after unsuspended, it returns error:

Passenger error #2

> An error occurred while trying to access '/home/cipg/public_html/config.ru': Cannot stat '/home/cipg/public_html/config.ru': Permission denied (13)
>   Apache doesn't have read permissions to that file. Please fix the relevant file permissions.

The latest backup doesn't have config.ru and tech hosting also doesn't have any clue.

Comment: You should have or obtain root privileges to the host and make sure `/home/cipg/public_tml/config.ru` has read (666) or something.

Comment: Hi Dave, the problem is config.ru is missing. Do you know what is that file? I downloaded symfony and no luck finding that file.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and searched a lot about this error and finally find a solution related to this problem
The problem is due to **domain** and **domain/config** directories. Just give executable permission to your domain config directories and it worked for me.

I found the solution [here](https://discussion.dreamhost.com/t/passenger-error-2/59722/3)

Just in case  if  someone facing the same problem will refer this